# Set feature accessExternalDTD in TransformerFactory

Tags: java, xml

For security reasons I'm adding the statement:

```
transformerFactory.setFeature("http://javax.xml.XMLConstants/property/accessExternalDTD", false);
```

However I'm getting the following error in the log files:

> 25-Nov-2014 09:35:48.802 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-14] CIMObject.CIMObjectCollectDataHANA.setRunningXML TransformerConfigurationException setRunningXMLHANA: javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException: Cannot set the feature 'http://javax.xml.XMLConstants/property/accessExternalDTD' on this TransformerFactory.

Someone experienced the same error and was able to fix it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It appears the problem is that such feature is not defined in `com/sun/org/apache/xalan/internal/utils/FeatureManager.java`.

If you are using java 8, then what you need to do is simply to call:

`transformerFactory.setFeature(XMLConstants.FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING, true);`

This is because in `com/sun/org/apache/xalan/internal/xsltctrax/TransformerFactoryImpl.java`:

```
if (value && XalanConstants.IS_JDK8_OR_ABOVE) {
    _xmlSecurityPropertyMgr.setValue(
         Property.ACCESS_EXTERNAL_DTD, 
         State.FSP, 
         XalanConstants.EXTERNAL_ACCESS_DEFAULT_FSP
    ); // ACCESS_EXTERNAL_DTD is disabled by setting to the default value
 }
```

Comment: @candied_orange Can you provide a full url to see the source codes?