# Document to String using DocumentBuilderFactory?

Tags: java, xml, dom, document

I am trying to find a way to convert [`Document`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Document.html) to `String` and found this [XML Document to String?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2567416/document-to-string) post here. But, I want to do the conversion [**without using `TransformerFactory` because of XXE Vulnerabilities**](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XML_External_Entity_%28XXE%29_Processing) and by using `DocumentBuilderFactory` only. I cannot upgrade to jdk8 because of other limitations.

I haven't had any luck so far with it; all the searches are returning the same code shown in the above link.

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 0):

This is difficult to do, but since your actual problem is the **security vulnerability** and not **`TransformerFactory`**, that may be a better way to go.

You should be able to configure `TransformerFactory` to ignore entities to prevent this sort of problem. See: [Preventing XXE Injection](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/82830/preventing-xxe-injection)

Another thing that may work for your security concerns is to use [`TransformerFactory.setFeature(XMLConstants.FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/TransformerFactory.html#setFeature%28java.lang.String,%20boolean%29). This should prevent the problems that you're worried about. See also [this forum thread on coderanch.](http://www.coderanch.com/t/631825/java/java/prevent-XML-External-Entity-Injection)

Comment: We can set FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING on TransformerFactory. But, we cannot set ACCESS_EXTERNAL_DTD, ACCESS_EXTERNAL_SCHEMA which are also needed. In JDK 8 by setting FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING will automatically set the other 2 features. JDK 6 and JDK 7 won't support these features which makes it incomplete solution.

Comment: @iranichai they aren't included in Java 7? Documentation seems to suggest they are

Comment: I see the exception 'javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException: Cannot set the feature 'http://javax.xml.XMLConstants/property/accessExternalDTD' on this TransformerFactory.' with jdk7 and found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27128578/set-feature-accessexternaldtd-in-transformerfactory

Comment: Also doing search brings up this bug report http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8016153 which says the issue is fixed in jdk8 with an affected version of jdk7u40

Answer (score 0):

Setting `FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING` may or may not help, depending on what implementation `TransformerFactory.getInstance()` actually returns.

For example in Java 7 with no additional XML libraries on classpath setting `transformerFactory.setFeature(XMLConstants.FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING, true);` does not help.

You can fix this by providing a `Source` other than `StreamSource` (which factory would need to parse using *some* settings that you do not control).

For example you can use `StAXSource` like this:

```
TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
transformerFactory.setFeature(XMLConstants.FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING, true); // does not help in Java 7
Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();

// StreamSource is insecure by default:
// Source source = new StreamSource(new StringReader(xxeXml));

// Source configured to be secure:
XMLInputFactory xif = XMLInputFactory.newFactory();
xif.setProperty(XMLInputFactory.IS_SUPPORTING_EXTERNAL_ENTITIES, false);
xif.setProperty(XMLInputFactory.SUPPORT_DTD, false);
XMLEventReader xmlEventReader = xif.createXMLEventReader(new StringReader(xxeXml));
Source source = new StAXSource(xmlEventReader);

transformer.transform(
        source,
        new StreamResult(new ByteArrayOutputStream()));
```

**Note** the actual `TrasformerFactory` may not actually support `StAXSource`, so you need to test your code with the classpath as it would be on production. For example Saxon 9 (old one, I know) does not support `StAXSource` and the only clean way of "fixing" it that I know is to provide custom `net.sf.saxon.Configuration` instance.