# Is it possible to avoid using xalan TransformerFactory?

Tags: java, xml, xalan

I have the following code:

```
final TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();

factory.setAttribute(XMLConstants.ACCESS_EXTERNAL_DTD, "");
```

The second line works fine in modern JDKs (I tried 1.8) with a default `TransformerFactory`. But when I add `xalan` (version 2.7.2, the most recent one) to classpath, I get the following on that second line:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not supported: http://javax.xml.XMLConstants/property/accessExternalDTD
    at org.apache.xalan.processor.TransformerFactoryImpl.setAttribute(TransformerFactoryImpl.java:571)
    at Main.main(Main.java:11)
```

I guess this is because xalan's `TransformerFactory` does not support this attribute. Xalan's implementation gets picked up through `ServiceLoader` mechanism: it is specified in `services/javax.xml.transform.TransfomerFactory` in xalan jar.

It is possible to override the `TransformerFactory` implementation using `javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory` system property or with `$JRE/lib/jaxp.properties` file, or pass class name directly in code. But to do it, I must supply a concrete class name. Right now, it is `com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl`, but it's a bit scary to hardcode it in a system property, as on JDK upgrade they can easily change the class name, and we will just get a runtime error.

Is there any way to instruct the `TransformerFactory.newInstance()` to just ignore that xalan-supplied implementation? Or tell it 'just use the system default'.

P.S. I cannot just remove `xalan` from classpath because a bunch of other libraries we use depend on it.

Comment: Are you trying to disable this feature?
If so, take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27128578/set-feature-accessexternaldtd-in-transformerfactory#29021326

Comment: @trappski Yes, I am trying to disable external DTD processing, so my question looks like an X/Y problem. But `factory.setFeature(XMLConstants.FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING, true)` doesn't prevent Xalan from accessing an external DTD: when I feed an XML with an external DTD link (an http link), Xalan tries to load that DTD and gets a `ConnectException`.

Answer (score 4):

The only thing I could achieve here is to hardcode JDK default factory and use the normal discovery process as a fallback:

```
TransformerFactory factory;
try {
   //the open jdk implementation allows the disabling of the feature used for XXE
    factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance("com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl", SecureXmlFactories.class.getClassLoader());
} catch (Exception | TransformerFactoryConfigurationError e) {
    //this part uses the default implementation of in xalan 2.7.2
   LOGGER.error("Cannot load default TransformerFactory, le's try the usual way", e);
   //not advisable if you dont want your application to be vulnerable. If needed you can put null here.
   factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();

}
```

and then configure it under `try/catch`

```
// this works everywhere, but it does not disable accessing
// external DTDs... still enabling it just in case
try {
    factory.setFeature(XMLConstants.FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING, true);
} catch (TransformerConfigurationException e) {
    LOGGER.error("Cannot enable secure processing", e);
}

// this does not work in Xalan 2.7.2
try {
    factory.setAttribute(XMLConstants.ACCESS_EXTERNAL_DTD, "");
} catch (Exception e) {
    LOGGER.error("Cannot disable external DTD access", e);
}
// this does not work in Xalan 2.7.2
try {
    factory.setAttribute(XMLConstants.ACCESS_EXTERNAL_STYLESHEET, "");
} catch (Exception e) {
    LOGGER.error("Cannot disable external stylesheet access", e);
}
```

And monitor the logs to see if/when the default JDK factory class name changes.

Comment: Please note the implementation in catch block `factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();` . it is not XXE safe and this logic will fail in case of attack.

Comment: Can you please let us know jar file name to use SecureXmlFactories.class file.

Comment: @ParameshKorrakuti `SecureXmlFactories` is the name of the class that includes the code shown as a proposed solution. You could just use the snippets shown here, class name is not important.

Comment: This answer matched my case 100%. However, I tried using this code `tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance("javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory", javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory.class.getClassLoader());` to get the instance from JDK instead from `org.apache.xalan.processor.TransformerFactoryImpl` but it's not working. I tried also  `tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance("org.apache.xalan.processor.TransformerFactoryImpl", javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory.class.getClassLoader());` and still coming from `xalan` please help!

Comment: Now I am able to wrap my head around this issue. Check my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75825877/4180447

Answer (score 0):

Another way to define which TransformerFactory implementation to load is by setting the `javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory` system property ([docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/TransformerFactory.html#newInstance--)).

In Ant you would do something like this inside your target:

```xml
<jvmarg value="-Djavax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory=com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl"/>
```

In the above example, I'm setting the one from OpenJDK8 as default

Answer (score 0):

This does not work with JAVA9 onwards. pass FactoryClass  and class loader to newInstance something like this

```
final TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance(                "com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl",
                CLASS_NAME.class.getClassLoader());
transformerFactory.setAttribute(XMLConstants.ACCESS_EXTERNAL_DTD, "");
        
transformerFactory.setAttribute(XMLConstants.ACCESS_EXTERNAL_STYLESHEET, "");
```