# Parsing Hazelcast 4.1 XmlClientConfig fails in Apache TomEE

Tags: hazelcast

Trying to construct a Hazelcast 4.1 client configuration from XML throws IllegalArgumentException if the application is running in Apache TomEE-Plus 8.0.0.

If executed in a standalone Java VM (AdoptOpenJDK 11.0.5), the problem does not occur.

Standalone test and TomEE use identical JDK.

Part of the stack trace:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Nicht unterstützt: http://javax.xml.XMLConstants/property/accessExternalDTD
    at org.apache.xalan.processor.TransformerFactoryImpl.setAttribute(TransformerFactoryImpl.java:571)
    at com.hazelcast.config.AbstractXmlConfigHelper.schemaValidation(AbstractXmlConfigHelper.java:109)
    at com.hazelcast.client.config.XmlClientConfigBuilder.parseAndBuildConfig(XmlClientConfigBuilder.java:175)
    at com.hazelcast.client.config.XmlClientConfigBuilder.build(XmlClientConfigBuilder.java:157)
    at com.hazelcast.client.config.XmlClientConfigBuilder.build(XmlClientConfigBuilder.java:150)
    at com.hazelcast.client.config.XmlClientConfigBuilder.build(XmlClientConfigBuilder.java:145)
    ...
```

I found a post on StackOverflow that seems to be related to my problem:
[Set feature accessExternalDTD in TransformerFactory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27128578/set-feature-accessexternaldtd-in-transformerfactory)
Unfortunately, I have no idea if the suggested solution in answer no. 1 really matches my problem.
And even if so, I do not know how to apply the suggested solution in application code or configurations only, without changes inside Hazelcast code.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Hazelcast Client-Config XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<hazelcast-client xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/client-config hazelcast-client-config-4.1.xsd"
                  xmlns="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/client-config"
                  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

    ...
 
</hazelcast-client>
```

TomEE version:

```
apache-tomee-plus-8.0.0 (Apache Tomcat Version 9.0.22)
```

Java version:

```
AdoptOpenJDK 11.0.5
IMPLEMENTOR="AdoptOpenJDK"
IMPLEMENTOR_VERSION="AdoptOpenJDK"
JAVA_VERSION="11.0.5"
JAVA_VERSION_DATE="2019-10-15"
MODULES="java.base java.compiler java.datatransfer java.xml java.prefs java.desktop java.instrument java.logging java.management java.security.sasl java.naming java.rmi java.management.rmi java.net.http java.scripting java.security.jgss java.transaction.xa java.sql java.sql.rowset java.xml.crypto java.se java.smartcardio jdk.accessibility jdk.internal.vm.ci jdk.management jdk.unsupported jdk.internal.vm.compiler jdk.aot jdk.charsets jdk.crypto.ec jdk.crypto.cryptoki jdk.dynalink jdk.httpserver jdk.internal.ed jdk.internal.le jdk.internal.vm.compiler.management jdk.jdwp.agent jdk.jfr jdk.jsobject jdk.localedata jdk.management.agent jdk.management.jfr jdk.naming.dns jdk.naming.rmi jdk.net jdk.pack jdk.scripting.nashorn jdk.scripting.nashorn.shell jdk.sctp jdk.security.auth jdk.security.jgss jdk.xml.dom jdk.zipfs"
OS_ARCH="x86_64"
OS_NAME="Linux"
SOURCE=".:git:7d14fe4b6f30"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like [this issue](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/issues/17839) which is due to the presence of an old JAXP implementation in the classpath. This is fixed in Hazelcast 4.1.1 ([fix pull request](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/pull/17842)) by supplying a system property switch to avoid failing when XXE protection cannot be turned on.

You should be able to start your Hazelcast client in Apache TomEE by upgrading to Hazelcast 4.1.1 and setting system property `hazelcast.ignoreXxeProtectionFailures=true` (for example by supplying `-Dhazelcast.ignoreXxeProtectionFailures=true` to Apache TomEE's `java` startup command line).

Comment: This is not what Hazelcast recommands. I think disabling a protection feature because of an outdated xml parser should not be the recommanded solution to this issue!

Comment: Indeed, disabling XXE is not the recommended resolution. Hazelcast 4.2 logs: `Enabling XXE protection failed. The attribute http://javax.xml.XMLConstants/property/accessExternalDTD is not supported by the TransformerFactory. This usually mean an outdated XML processor is present on the classpath (e.g. Xerces, Xalan). If you are not able to resolve the issue by fixing the classpath, the hazelcast.ignoreXxeProtectionFailures system property can be used to disable XML External Entity protections. We don't recommend disabling the XXE as such the XML processor configuration is unsecure`

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an issue with XML / DTD . Please check with the following config file
https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/blob/master/hazelcast/src/main/resources/hazelcast-client-default.xml
and code

```
public ClientConfig clientConfig() throws Exception {
  return new XmlClientConfigBuilder("hazelcast-client.xml").build();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can exclude the xercesImpl and xalan from esapi dependency.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.owasp.esapi</groupId>
        <artifactId>esapi</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0.0</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>xerces</groupId>
                <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>xalan</groupId>
                <artifactId>xalan</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```